# ASP:Repeater not visible after databinding?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asprepeater

I am attempting to create a simple mobile view of a website and would like a list of product categories to display on the homepage... however when I try to generate a list of categories from a DataTable is just kinda doesn't. Nothing is visible, as if the repeater took the day off and went home.

Here's code:

```
        Dim dt As DataTable = Categories.GetMainCategories(Request("MainID"))
    rptCatButtons.DataSource = dt
    Dim catName As String = Categories.GetMainCategoryName(Request("MainID"))
    'Dim catButton As Button = CType(rptCatButtons.FindControl("btnCategories"), Button)

    catButton.Text = catName
    rptCatButtons.DataBind()
```

And ASP:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/count.js"></script>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptCatButtons" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
<div class="category-mobile" runat="server"><asp:Button ID="btnCategories" runat="server" Text="Hello" class="category-mobile-button"></asp:Button></div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

It's pretty basic code right now, because I took code from a different page (where it does generate a menu) and tried it here, but no go so I've messed around with it a bit.

I've also tried binding the table in the Pre_Init and Page_Init sections but neither made any difference (except a couple of neat Null Object References).

Assistance please?

Comment: what is the use of the repeater here? i don't see any data being displayed from the datasource. you're just creating a button inside a div for the no of rows your datasource returns.

Comment: This could be the problem, I'm attempting to get a list of page categories for an ecommerce site. This function does the trick on another page but the stored functions it references do jack all on my new page.